# Android studio search results view

Tags: java, android, json, layout, view

I have search and results activities. After submitting a search, webserver is contacted and i will get json array as a result. Each object in that array will contain few info pairs about that result.
I've made view design for results but i don't know how to copy and re-use that view for all search results, creating one text view for results would be simple, but what to do with this complicated layout?
This is code of view i want to copy and use for each result...
Also, i want results to be clickable and when clicked to be taken to details page where more details about that should be shown, so second question is how to keep track of what have user clicked (btw. i know ID's are messed up, i will set them later)

```
<LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/result"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:paddingRight="15dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/background_border"
            android:onClick="ShowDetails">

            <ImageView
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/golettaverde"
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/image_background_border"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:text="Goletta Verde"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/textView5"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textColor="?attr/colorButtonNormal"
                    android:textStyle="normal|bold"
                    android:textSize="26sp"
                    android:layout_height="10dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:text="5 seats - 18.60 meters"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/textView6"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textColor="?attr/colorButtonNormal"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                    android:layout_height="7dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:text="Year 2009"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/textView7"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textColor="?attr/colorButtonNormal"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                    android:layout_height="7dp" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1">

                    <ImageView
                        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_on"
                        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_width="30dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                    <ImageView
                        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_on"
                        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_width="30dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                    <ImageView
                        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_on"
                        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_width="30dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                    <ImageView
                        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_on"
                        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_width="30dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                    <ImageView
                        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_on"
                        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_width="30dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:text="300€"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/textView7"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="24sp"
                    android:textColor="?attr/colorButtonNormal"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                    android:layout_height="7dp"
                    android:textStyle="normal|bold" />
```

Comment: I see no real question here. Please be more specific.

Comment: How to use this layout that i have copied (LinearLayout with all its sublayouts) for all results (i dont know how many results will be, can be 3 and can be 50, so how to create X copys of this layout and fill them with info from json object) and how to keep track on what user have clicked? Same questions are written up in the post.

Comment: Don't use the comments to add contents about your question. Edit your question instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can use a [Recycler View](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) for the purpose.It's easy to use and the most efficient way for your task.You just need to initialise your view and it will work your way.You can watch [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wq2o4EbM74k) to learn how to use recycler view.
2. To make your view clickable,you need to add

   `android:foreground="?selectableItemBackground"`

   to the root tag of your view.
3. You can give an ID or a tag to each list object you created in recycler view to know which item is clicked and act accordingly.

Hope it works for you.Cheers!

Comment: I think thats what i need, thanks

Comment: Cool. Please upvote the answer if it solves your problem! Happy Coding! ;)